# Mutton shoulder versus mutton leg - any difference in length of cooking?

Tags: meat, cooking-time, slow-cooking, mutton

I cooked mutton shoulder like advised in the answer for [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13390/how-to-prepare-mutton-so-its-not-tough). It was under the foil and was cooked in the oven for like 3 hours.

Now I have mutton leg instead of shoulder. The size is similar. Should the cooking time be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leg is usually leaner than shoulder and so doesn't benefit from a long slow cook. A quicker, hotter roast is generally best, something on the order of 2-2.5 hours @ 220C for a good-size leg. Let it rest for a good half hour afterwards.